# Почему блокировка изменения окна в python-kivy (Config.set) не работает?

Tags: python, kivy

Я использовал метод Config.set("graphics","resizable", '0') но размеры окна все равно изменялись, вот код

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
'''from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from pygments.lexers import HtmlLexer'''

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics","resizable", '0')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        #return CodeInput(lexer=HtmlLexer())

        return Button(text = 'This is my first button',
                      font_size=30,
                      on_press = self.btn_press,
                      background_color = [.16,.16,.14,1],
                      background_normal = ''
                      )

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        print('the button was clicked')
        instance.text = 'I was cliked'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: попробуйте явно указать размеры Config.set('graphics', 'width', 500)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 500)

Comment: cпасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

**Конфиги нужно прописывать до всех остальных импортов**

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics","resizable", '0') # вот так

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        #return CodeInput(lexer=HtmlLexer())

        return Button(text = 'This is my first button',
                      font_size=30,
                      on_press = self.btn_press,
                      background_color = [.16,.16,.14,1],
                      background_normal = ''
                      )

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        print('the button was clicked')
        instance.text = 'I was cliked'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```